# Not able to load argo workflow UI

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

I am trying to follow this documentation https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/quick-start/

To set up argo pod in my kubernetes ,everything works fine but when I am loading the ui in browser it is stuck at loading

The complete page is not loading some how
Apart from port forwarding i tried creating a load balancer service as well but still it doesn't work

Any idea how to load the ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue ,I guess there is some problem with the master branch

so instead of creating deployment with master branch

> kubectl apply -n argo -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/manifests/quick-start-postgres.yaml

use stable branch like below

> kubectl apply -n argo -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/stable/manifests/quick-start-postgres.yaml

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me and I am fairly certain it is this [regression bug](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/8781) that was just opened. There are two different workarounds in the comments in the link that you may want to try.

I attempted the first suggestion. I created a local copy of the [manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/manifests/quick-start-postgres.yaml) and changed the version tag for `argocli` from `quay.io/argoproj/argocli:latest` to `quay.io/argoproj/argocli:v3.2.11`. I then ran the command as:

```
kubectl apply -f <filepath/to/my/copy>
```

Rather than using the line from the tutorial where you pull from their repo.

If you care and intend to use workflows in more than just the tutorial sense, you should open the linked bug and give it a thumbs up.